# Using Linq to Query a Service Reference

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I have SharePoint custom workflow wherein I need to query a database. I have a service reference where I can see all the tables in the database but I have no idea how to query it.

I've tried using the common

```
ServiceReference sr = new ServiceReference();
var x = from s in sr where condition
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I get an error like 'Where' not found in the service reference. Has anyone tried doing this? I'd like to avoid using the SqlClient if that's possible using Linq

Comment: It sayis it cannot find an implementation of the query pattern for the source type.

Comment: `sr` is a reference to the object, how can you make a linq query on it in the first place...?

Comment: I just patterend to what I see in examples over the internet. They create an instance of the object (ie. a list) and then queries on it. That's why I'm asking if it's possible to do the same using a service reference.

Comment: He says he can see all the tables from the `ServiceReference` object. means he can access via linq: var x = from s in sr.Table where s.field == "condition" select s;

Comment: I think you are looking for this...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148142.aspx

Comment: Btw whats the source type of `ServiceReference`? Try change `ServiceReference sr = new ServiceReference();` to `var sr = new ServiceReference();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `ServiceReference()` looks like but I will give you an example how can you do a LINQ query.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceReference sr = new ServiceReference();

        var listWithWhereCondition = from s in sr where s.Name == "Name2" select s;

        foreach (var item in listWithWhereCondition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceReference : IEnumerable<TestClass>
{
    private IEnumerable<TestClass> _testList;

    public ServiceReference()
    {
        _testList = new List<TestClass> { 
            new TestClass {
                Name = "Name1"
            },
            new TestClass {
                Name = "Name2"
            },
            new TestClass {
                Name = "Name2"
            }
        };
    }

    public IEnumerator<TestClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in _testList)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```